# python multiline list output and sorting

Tags: python, list, python-3.7, any

A query produces multiple lines answer, not always all lines have any  output/result, and would produce an empty row `[]`

**I want to**

1. when any line has a result to be shown and ignore all other empty rows [Case 1]
2. if **all rows** are empty print out **one single message**. [Case 2]

I have tried a number of options with loop statement `if & else` and `all()` or `any()` however my best shot is to fulfil the first requirement only- ***I am unable to get the second requirement for all empty***.

a snippet of the code that only delivers the 1st requirement

```
    f = query(data)
    for x in f:
        if x:
            print(x)
        else:
            if all(x):
               print("no f found")
```

also, I have tried both `any()` and `all()` and their `not` variation with no luck

Case 1
the output of f query, when there are some results, [in this case only 2 results out of 4]

```
['p=SDVjXSERgCziEsyhT4dIySuh9ha5Udt5b9F5TATeJ']
[]
['p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC31']
[]
```

desire output

```
p=SDVjXSERgCziEsyhT4dIySuh9ha5Udt5b9F5TATeJ
p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC31
```

Case 2, the output of f query, when there is no result at all

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

desire output

```
no f found
```

**What **I don't want** is to get a ** `no f found` **for each row** that is empty

```
p=SDVjXSERgCziEsyhT4dIySuh9ha5Udt5b9F5TATeJ
no f found
p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC31
no f found
```

**or**

```
no f found
no f found
no f found
no f found
```

would really appreciate if anyone can give me a hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this easily by introducing a variable, found:

```
found = False
f = query(data)
for x in f:
    if x:
        print(x)
        found = True

if not found:
    print("no f found")
```

'if not any(f)' might work too, but it's fine to use a variable like that when you first traverse the list anyway, so you get the info without doing it again with any().

With any() this might be a nice way:

```
f = query(data)
if not any(f):
    print("no f found")
else:
    for x in f:
        if x:
            print(x)
```

Comment: i tried both options and still give `no f found` for all lines ```no f found
no f found
no f found
no f found ```

Comment: that's not possible - in my examples the 'no f found' print is outside the 'for' loop, it can only be outputted once.

Comment: i think i got it now - i had another def and when i moved the not found outside the main def, it worked, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can simply use a flag to indicate if there are any results. If the flag is raised, only the results will be printed. Otherwise, "no f found" will be printed:

```
array = [['p=SDVjXSERgCziEsyhT4dIySuh9ha5Udt5b9F5TATeJ'],
     [],
     ['p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC31'],
     []]

flag_some = False
for a in array:
      if a:
            print(a)
            flag_some = True

if not flag_some:
      print("no f found")
```

Comment: problem is still it gives output for each line, so 4 line of no f found rather than one single line

Comment: thanks, i had to move the flag outside the current def, and it worked - cheers